# boost geometry polygon insert point at index

Tags: c++, boost, polygon, boost-geometry

How can I add a point at the index of the polygon?

Insert point(2.5, 7.5) at correct index.

output :

(((0, 0), (0, 5), (5, 5), (5, 0), (0, 0), (2.5, 7.5)))

-------------------   ▼

(((0, 0), (0, 5), (2.5, 7.5), (5, 5), (5, 0), (0, 0)))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point> polygon;


    polygon poly;

    boost::geometry::append ( poly, point(0, 0) );
    boost::geometry::append ( poly, point(0, 5) );
    boost::geometry::append ( poly, point(5, 5) );
    boost::geometry::append ( poly, point(5, 0) );
    boost::geometry::append ( poly, point(0, 0) );

    poly.outer().push_back( point(2.5, 7.5) );

    std::cout << boost::geometry::dsv(poly) << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand poly.outer is just a std::vector, so you should be able to use the [insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) method to place the value at the desired index:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

int  main()
{
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double>  point;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point>        polygon;

    polygon  poly;

    boost::geometry::append(poly, point(0, 0));
    boost::geometry::append(poly, point(0, 5));
    boost::geometry::append(poly, point(5, 5));
    boost::geometry::append(poly, point(5, 0));
    boost::geometry::append(poly, point(0, 0));

    // Insert point at index 2
    auto &outer_ring = poly.outer();
    outer_ring.insert(outer_ring.begin() + 2, point(2.5, 7.5));

    std::cout << boost::geometry::dsv(poly) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**The output is:**

```
(((0, 0), (0, 5), (2.5, 7.5), (5, 5), (5, 0), (0, 0)))
```

Comment: it is way more complicate that this, you need to find correct point to put it, which is not trivial.